# How to change js URL object pathname and protocol properties?

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to change the pathname and protocol of `window.location.href`, to a new string.

```js
const getUrl = new URL(window.location.href); //'https://example.com/questions'
```

I'm trying to create a new variable from the above, so it becomes:

```js
'https://api.example.com/parameter'
```

I can see in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) I have access to the pathname and protocol, which are the bits I want to change, but how do I actually change them? My attempt:

```js
const newURL = getURL
    .replace(getURL.protocol, 'https://api')
    .replace(getURL.pathname, '/parameter');
```

However, with this I get an error like `'VM825:1 Uncaught TypeError: getURL.replace is not a function'`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getURL` variable contains an object you can modify, so changing its `host` and `pathname`, you can obtain the URL you mentioned. You can see a demo below:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href); // https://example.com/questions
url.host = "api.example.com";
url.pathname = "/parameter";

const href = url.href; // https://api.example.com/parameter
console.log(href);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.